# unmarshal custom value map

Tags: go

I have created a custom type for a map. I would like to unmarshal an array
json response into the map. The key value of the map changes each time the response is received. The issue I have is the unmarshal function does not map correctly to the custom values.

```golang
    type id map[string]yp

    type yp struct {
        f1      string              
        f2      int     
    }   

    func main() {
        data := []byte("[{\"unique1\":{\"f1\":\"1\",\"f2\":\"2\"}},{\"unique2\":{\"f1\":\"4\",\"f2\":\"7\"}}]")
        var i []id
        json.Unmarshal(data,&i)
        fmt.Printf("%v",i)
    }
```

Comment: Your JSON has `f2` as a string type, but your struct has `f2` as `int`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the source value for `f2` is string, you need to add a field tag:

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/json"
   "fmt"
)

var data = []byte(`
[
   {
      "unique1": {"f1": "1", "f2": "2"}
   }, {
      "unique2": {"f1": "4", "f2": "7"}
   }
]
`)

func main() {
   var ids []map[string]struct {
      F1 string              
      F2 int `json:"f2,string"`
   }
   json.Unmarshal(data, &ids)
   // [map[unique1:{F1:1 F2:2}] map[unique2:{F1:4 F2:7}]]
   fmt.Printf("%+v\n", ids)
}
```